# Elastic search and kibana not running in browser

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to install Elastic search and kibanna in my linux server, both elastic search and kibana service started, but i cannot able to to go the URL. [This site cannot be reached - http://127.0.0.1:9203/ http://localhost:5601
both i have tried]

[image]

[image]

Please help to update, what could be the issue. Is there any port level change i need to do ? please guide

Comment: Your ES seems to bind on port 9200 and not 9203

Comment: sorry, even i tried the port 9200 also. It's not working, i tried 9200 to 9203

Comment: From where are you trying to access your Kibana?

Comment: Is it your local server ?

Comment: Check the binding ip of the kibana in kibana.yml to be 0.0.0.0 in case your kibana is running on the same machine as that of elastic, where as the elastic ip is provided as [your system ip]:9200 instead of localhost. Also, check if your firewall is on (it might be blocking it) consider turning it off or setting up rules

Comment: I'm running in my local server

Comment: Do you configured kibana.yml ?

Comment: No i didn't touch kibana.yml file in config

Comment: un comment this line ' elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200" ' on kibana.yml inside config.

Comment: Default ports of ES and kibana are 9200 and 5601 respectively .

Comment: Nidhin, I have un-commented  that line, but i'm getting port in use error  log   [09:22:06.241] [fatal] Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!
FATAL Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!

Comment: You can use netstat to see which process is listening on 5601 (e.g., `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 5601` on linux). You can kill it by the process id (in case you don't know where it's running).